# What does "en avoir" mean?

Tags: sens, en

I know that the pronoun "en" is usually used to replace a prepositional phrase of "de" + a noun. However, what does it mean without any context?
I'm trying to comprehend the following phrase from an essay named "[Le vin et le lait](https://bigbazar.wordpress.com/2007/11/22/le-vin-et-le-lait-roland-barthes/)" by Roland Barthes:

> on sait que l’un des mythes propres à l’intellectuel moderne, c’est l’obsession « d’en avoir »

What kind of obsession does the modern intellectual have?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What Barthes says is that modern intellectuals try to be "real men" (and not men who can only think and never act) so they do "real men" things, i.e. drink wine.
"En avoir" actually refers back to "virilité naturelle" and means "to have balls". Excuse the French...

Comment: Merci beaucoup, what is the purpose of the quotes here? I.e why is it `«d'en avoir»` instead of just `d'en avoir`?

Comment: @dimid: The purpose is to distantiate oneself from the crudeness of the expression.

Comment: @Stéphane, perhaps you mean to distance oneself from. I really do not think one can say that Roland Barthes uses a crude expression here. He is really one of the most careful, creative and eulogized writers in French letters in the 1960-70's. To say pure cérébralité is to be mocking intellectualité. I don't think the intellectuals were worried about having balls. They were worried about their intellectual output.

Comment: Also, in all my years in France, I never heard en avoir to mean to have balls. It would mean reading into the text avoir des couilles, and I think that's a reach. But maybe you are right. It's a possibility.

Comment: It is not a possibility. That is what he means. He does what he says intellectuals did to bridge the gap between them and the working class in '68.

Comment: What does he do??

Comment: use a crude expression,same as drinking wine like the working class

Comment: @Lambie "en avoir" definitely means "having balls" without a referent for "en", and the use of "en"is a way to avoid saying "balls". One can also say "en avoir dans le pantalon".

Comment: if you look at this quote in the full [context](https://bigbazar.wordpress.com/2007/11/22/le-vin-et-le-lait-roland-barthes/), it becomes clear that *en avoir* is having balls: the preceding sentence clearly says wine is a way to manliness for intellectuals. So the hint at balls definitely makes sense. *En avoir* is a very common phrase for "having balls". Why would Barthes not be allowed to use it ?

Comment: At first, glance, it just seemed so crude. Generally, he wasn't a crude man. But upon reconsidering it I agree that it's avoir des couilles.

Answer (score -1):

When asking about EN, you have to provide context or the antecedent. So I have taken the liberty of doing so:

[...]le vin le délivrera des mythes, lui ôtera de son intellectualité, l'égalera au prolétaire; par le vin, l'intellectuel s'approche d'une virilité naturelle, et pense ainsi échapper à la malédiction qu'un siècle et demi de romantisme continue à faire peser sur la cérébralité pure (on sait que l'un des mythes propres à l'intellectuel moderne, c'est l'obsession «d'en avoir»).

**avoir de** followed by an uncountable noun becomes EN if you refer back to it: for example, avoir du lait, avoir de la peine, **avoir de la cérébalité pure**. If you remove the noun, the pronoun that replaces it is EN.

The en pronoun refers back to "cérébalité pure" or pure cerebrality. For milk, the EN would be translated as: to have some [of it]. And **here, to have some also**. **Only not milk, but rather some of that pure cerebrality**.

**Kindly note**: Since the word is Latin based and in English, we have the same adjective as in French, I am coining the word in English as Barthes did in French.

[...] on sait que l'un des mythes propres à l'intellectuel moderne, c'est l'obsession «d'en avoir»

[...] we know that one of the myths proper to the modern intellectual is an obsession with "having some" of this. [You can leave off the of this if that seems better to you.]

[Barthes' text called Le Vin et Le Lait](http://palimpsestes.fr/textes_philo/barthes/vin.html)

Comment: Merci beaucoup, what is the purpose of the quotes here? I.e why is it `«d'en avoir»` instead of just `d'en avoir`?

Comment: Well, given the text, he is being sarcastic. By putting it in quotes he is suggesting it is a quasi-physical object that you can "have" [as in get or own]. This is just my own opinion. The text is about wine or milk, both of which you can have, as in have in your fridge or cupboard. It's rather amusing. Like a thing you get from a supermarket shelf. In other words, a commodity.

Comment: I may be wrong and Stéphane is probably right. That was, however, not my first reading.